# Gravitational Waves and Quantum Gravity

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles

Since we can now directly observe gravitational wave signals, can any type of future experiment be set up that might manifest the quantum nature of gravity?  For example, perhaps a version of LIGO that has some type of double slit or quantum eraser apparatus?  Maybe this can at least place limits on the properties of the hypothesized graviton.

Is any research being done on this area?

Comment: see https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/quantum-gravity/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235019/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/419589/2451  and links therein.